# JavaScript/Sublime Text: swap single and double quote keys

Tags: javascript, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am a JavaScript programmer using Sublime Text.  I prefer using double quotes to single quotes.  Is there a way or a plugin where we can swap the key press of single and double quote?

Please note I am aware of plugins (like SublimeChangeQuotes ) which does this on a file or on a selection of text.  But that is not what I am looking for.

What I am looking for is: On key press for single quote should produce double quote and on key press of double quote (with shift key) should produce single quote.  All these while I am typing my JavaScript code.

JavaScript code quality tools like jshint, jscs, etc expects the strings to be double quoted.  That is why double quote is used very frequently in JavaScript coding.

Why do I need this? Simple, just to avoid pressing shift key every time I need double quote.

Comment: I can't help you in that :) Also i wouldn't recommend it because with single quotes you don't need to escape html values. But it's your personal choice, unlike PHP, ECMAScript doesn't have any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Go to "Key Bindings - User" from "Preferences"

2) Add the following two lines, which basically does this swapping.

```
{ "keys": ["\""], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "'$0'"} },
{ "keys": ["'"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\"$0\""} }
```

These lines should be placed in the array seen in the key binding file.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to re-map keys in the Windows registry without any third party tools, but an easier and safer way to do it is to use something like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).  I use it to re-map the '\' key above Enter to Enter, because I never got over keyboard designers taking away the big L-shaped Enter key!

To use it, install and run AutoHotKey.  It will give you a default script, which you can edit by adding the following lines:

```
'::"

"::'
```

This will swap over the two inputs.

If you want the mapping to only affect a single program you can put the script in an "if" block as follows, using the window name or a few other identifiers:

```
IfWinActive("Sublime Text")
{
    '::"

    "::'
}
```

My syntax may not be perfect, I'm operating from memory - [here is a link to the IfWinActive docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfWinActive.htm) if you need more help.

Comment: Can this be done for a specific app? Rather than the whole system?

Comment: Thanks Ivan for the idea.  I'll wait for a sublime text solution for some time before accepting your answer.

Comment: No problem, I understand you'd like to avoid using a 3rd party tool if this is all you want it for.  If you haven't tried using AutoHotKey before though I think you'll find it very addictive, not just for this but for all sorts of applications!  (It works great for games that require key combinations to perform certain actions!)

Comment: The following code didn't work for me:                                                           
`'::"`
`"::'`
I had to use the following code:
`+"::`\n 
 `Send, '`\n
`return`\n
`'::"`

The order of this mattered.